# PrintDialog not modal

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5, printdialog

I'm using [System.Windows.Control.PrintDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) in my .NET-3.5 wpf app. Unfortunately, the print dialog will not be modal even though I'm using [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.showdialog(v=vs.110).aspx). There doesn't seem to be any way for my to set the owner to be my app either. Ideas?

Comment: You could only flub this if you call ShowDialog() on a worker thread.  Don't do that.

Comment: If you don't want to call ShowDialog(), you can write your own `DocumentPaginator`s, manage your `PrinterServer`, `PrintQueue`, `PrintCapabilities`, etc. and you can write your own print preview and call `PrintDialog.PrintDocument`.  Its a great deal of work.